# Can matlab read data from a file link?

Tags: matlab

Question says it all:  in a Windows OS,  is there a way to make Matlab's  `csvread` or `importdata`  recognize that  it needs to follow `myfile.csv.lnk` to the source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab can't process windows shortcut style symbolic links, but it has no problem with [ntfs symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) which were added around Vista and are transparent to applications.  I've tested both the symbolic and hard link variants of these and both work fine through Matlab.

You make them using the `mklink` command, similar to this

```
mklink test.lnk test.txt
```